# AWS EC2 command not found

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, centos7

Created a new EC2 Instance with Centos 7, first thing i typed yum update, it says yum: command not found

```
# cat /etc/*-release
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)


# whereis yum
yum: /etc/yum /usr/etc/yum
```

Tried almost everything I could find on internet. Any solutions?

Comment: What do you see when you run `echo $PATH`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I got it, I was using community AMI, it might be broken. Got Centos7 from marketplace, it worked.